# Working with Hibernate 3 and Struts 2. The cgf file is not getting read. Is it because of the JARS?

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my `DAO

```
    package com.sheeba;

    import com.sheeba.LeavePojo;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.hibernate.Criteria;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
    import org.hibernate.Session;

    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;

    import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
    import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;

    public class LeaveDAO {

        @SessionTarget
        Session session;

        @TransactionTarget
        Transaction trans;

        List<LeavePojo> myList = new ArrayList<LeavePojo>();

        // LeavePojo pojoObj=new LeavePojo();
        public String saveToDb(LeavePojo pojoObj) {
            try {

                System.out.println("inside saveToDb method-before query");
                System.out.println("bank id" + pojoObj.getBank_id());
                // Serializable isSaved =session.save(pojoObj);
                System.out.println("session" + session);
                session.saveOrUpdate(pojoObj);

                // System.out.println("llllllllllllllllllllllll"+session.save(pojoObj).getClass().getName());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "SUCCESS";
        }

        public List<LeavePojo> retrieveData() {
            myList = session.createQuery("from LeavePojo").list();
            return myList;
        }

        /*public String fetchBankId()
            {
              try{
                  System.out.println("inside fetch  bank id -- before query");
                  String hql = "SELECT l.bank_id FROM LeavePojo l";
                  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
                  System.out.println("deeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+query.list());
                  List results = query.list();
                 System.out.println("RESSSSSSSSSSSUUUUUUUUUUUUUULLLLLLLLLTttasssss"+results);
                  }catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }

        return"success";


        }*/}



service

    package com.sheeba;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

import com.sheeba.*;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.InterceptorRef;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;

@ParentPackage("hibernate-default")
@InterceptorRef("basicStackHibernate")
public class LeaveService implements ModelDriven {
    LeavePojo modobj = new LeavePojo();
    LeaveDAO leaveDAO=new LeaveDAO();
    //private LeaveDAO leaveDAO;                                   // this is the dependency injection

    public LeaveDAO getLeaveDAO() {
        return leaveDAO;
    }

    public void setLeaveDAO(LeaveDAO leaveDAO) {
        this.leaveDAO = leaveDAO;
    }


    public List<LeavePojo> myList = new ArrayList<LeavePojo>();

    public List<LeavePojo> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<LeavePojo> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public List<LeavePojo> saveDetailsService(LeavePojo modobj) {

        System.out.println("inside savedetails service");
        leaveDAO.saveToDb(modobj);
        myList = leaveDAO.retrieveData();

        return myList;

    }



    @Override
    public Object getModel() {

        return modobj;
    }


}
```

This is action

```
package com.sheeba;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.NEW;

public class LeaveAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<LeavePojo> {
    LeaveService ls=new LeaveService();
    LeavePojo pojo =new LeavePojo();
    public List<LeavePojo> myList = new ArrayList<LeavePojo>();

    public List<LeavePojo> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(List<LeavePojo> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }
    private String bank_id;
    private String emp_name;
    private String leaves_applied;

    public String getBank_id() {
        return bank_id;
    }

    public void setBank_id(String bank_id) {
        this.bank_id = bank_id;
    }

    public String getEmp_name() {
        return emp_name;
    }

    public void setEmp_name(String emp_name) {
        this.emp_name = emp_name;
    }

    public String getLeaves_applied() {
        return leaves_applied;
    }

    public void setLeaves_applied(String leaves_applied) {
        this.leaves_applied = leaves_applied;
    }

    public String getServiceLasyer(){
        try{
        System.out.println(pojo.getBank_id()+"is bank id");
         myList=ls.saveDetailsService(pojo);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return SUCCESS;

    }

    @Override
    public LeavePojo getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pojo;
    }



}
```

Have used these jars here /AAAAANEWPROJECT/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate3.jar
/AAAAANEWPROJECT/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations-3.2.1.ga.jar
/AAAAANEWPROJECT/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-core.jar
/AAAAANEWPROJECT/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-2.2.2-GA.jar. for hibernate.

struts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd"> 
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default,hibernate-default">
<action name="saveAction" class="com.sheeba.LeaveAction" method="getServiceLasyer">
<result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
</action>

</package> 
</struts>
```

hib.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM  
"hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://10.112.178.78:1433;databaseName=Test_DB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">TestUser1</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Test123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <mapping resource="LeavePojo.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

hib.mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM  
"hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sheeba.LeavePojo" table="LeavePojo">
        <id name="bank_id" type="string" column="BANK_ID">
        </id>
        <property name="emp_name" column="EMP_NAME" type="string" />
        <property name="leaves_applied" column="LEAVES_APPLIED" type="string" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am not able to get the output. 404 error comes. Is there any problem with the jar?

Comment: I tried with various other DTDs. Nothing seem to work! :(

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace!

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved! I downloaded from the sourceforge DTD and added it to my root directory which is SRC folder. 
And, edited the hibernate.cfg.xml to be as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM  
"hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

by this way the application doesnt have to hit the URL but it points and finds the DTD in the src folder. this you can do when you are using your system online. 
IT worked for me after hell a lot of researches!!